# Prove or disprove: if $B_{1}$ is $R-$submodule of $B$, then $f^{-1}(B_{1})$ is $R-$submodule of $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, modules

Suppose $f:A\rightarrow B$ is homomorphism of $R-$modules $A$ and $B$. Prove or disprove: if $B_{1}$ is $R-$submodule of $B$, then $f^{-1}(B_{1})$ is $R-$submodule of $A$.

My proof:
We know that $f^{-1}(B)$ is subgroup of $A$. Still needs to be shown: $rx\in f^{-1}(B_{1})$, $\forall r \in R, x \in f^{-1}(B_{1})$. Since it is $x \in f^{-1}(B_{1})$ then $f(x) \in B_{1}$. Then we have: $f(rx)=rf(x) \in B_{1}$ from which it follows $rx \in f^{-1}(B_{1})$. I hope the proof is correct.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Hi, this site is not to be used as a pre-grading service.  Posts of the form "problem-solution-is-this-right" (or even worse "i-hope-this-is-right") are not appropriate.  If you have a solution that has a place where you are stuck and have questions about if you can or can't do something, that sticking point can act as a premise for your post.